# How to reference a function as text in Google sheet cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to reference the name of two functions, but writing in text format in the cell

When I use within a formula it works, in a good way.

```
= Woo_processing (url)
```

OK, the CSV files are downloaded, everything works so far

But I want to reference the Woo_processing (url) function in a cell

A2 = "Woo_processing (url)" (plain text in the cell)

I Tried

```
=formulatext(A2)
```

But this works for formulas.

AND FOR FUNCTION?

Answer (score 0):

try one of these 3:

```
=INDIRECT("A2")
```

---

```
=A2
```

---

```
=Sheet1!A2
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for listening. But I tried indirect, the other options quoted are very basic and do not work

Comment: Thank you for your interest.

Basically there is no spreadsheet.

The code is only
= Woo_processing (url)

I believe a custom script function can not be called from a text in a cell. Unless someone proves otherwise.

Comment: Formulatext , i tried too.  Its aren’t fOrmula, is a fuction